# Getting the specific char from text and print the related line in C

Tags: c, file, io

I have couple problems with I/O file process in C. I have a text file like this:

```
AAA    1    80
BBB    1    60
CCC    2    20
DDD    1    70
EEE    2    15
FFF    2    30
GGG    2    75
HHH    1    25
JJJ    2    35
```

My aim is if the user enters 1 I need to print:

```
AAA    1    80
BBB    1    60
DDD    1    70
HHH    1    25
```

And sum up their values(80+60+70+25) and apply same things if user enters 2.

I code something such that:

```
FILE *fPtr;
    char str[MAXCHAR];
    char* fileName = "/home/levent/Masaüstü/data.txt";
    int productType;

    fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(fPtr == NULL){
        printf("Error! Colud not find file %s", fileName);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter product type code (1 or 2): ");
    scanf("%d", &productType);

    while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fPtr) != NULL){
        printf("%s", str);        
    }
```

As you assume this code prints entire text file. How can I manage my aim?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fscanf` and parse each component of each line, then in the same cycle you can sum the valid values:

Here is a possible impelementation with some comments:

[**Live demo**](https://repl.it/join/hxzgicph-anastaciu)

```c
//...
#define MAXCHAR 100
//...
int fileProductType; //product type read from file
int value;           //value read from file
int sum = 0;         //to store the sum of the values

//...

//scan all file lines
while (fscanf(fPtr, "%99s %d %d", str, &fileProductType, &value) == 3){
    if (productType == fileProductType){ //if the type is correct
        printf("%s %d %d\n", str, fileProductType, value); //print line 
        sum += value; //sum values
    }    
}

if(sum)                       //if the product type is found
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum); //print sum
else
    puts("No mach found!");
//...
```

Another option would be to use `sscanf` to parse the components from each line read by `fgets`. The rest would be more or less the same.